# Triple integral over a region bounded by surfaces.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

The problem is to calculate
$$I=\underset{S}{\iiint}x^2\;dV,$$
where $S$ is the region bounded by $x+y^2=1$, $x+z^2=1$ and the plane $zy$.

In my conclusions (that follows from [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rASKzEbMXIQ) reasoning and probably are wrong), the [value of the integral](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E1%28%20int_0%5E%281-x%29%5E%281%2F2%29%20%28int_0%5E%281-x%29%5E%281%2F2%29%20x%5E2%20dz%29%20dy%29%20dx) in the first octant is

$$J=\int_0^1\int_0^{\sqrt{1-x}}\int_0^{\sqrt{1-x}}x^2\;dz\;dy\;dx=\frac{1}{12}$$

and thus $I=2J=1/6$.

However, the book says that the answer is $1/3$. So, could someone tell me what is wrong and what is the correct way of write $I$ as an interated integral?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you only doubling it? Your region consists of four octants, not two.

Comment: @Semiclassical You're right. Thanks.